# How to check if a Pandas Dataframe column contains a value?

Tags: pandas

I'd like to check if a pandas.DataFrame column contains a specific value. For instance, this toy Dataframe has a `"h"` in column `"two"`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array(list("abcdefghi")).reshape((3, 3)),
    columns=["one", "two", "three"]
)
df
  one two three
0   a   b     c
1   d   e     f
2   g   h     i
```

But surprisingly,

```
"h" in df["two"]
```

evaluates to `False`.

My question is: What's the clearest way to find out if a DataFrame column (or `pandas.Series` in general) contains a specific value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df["two"]` is a `pandas.Series` which looks like this:

```
0    b
1    e
2    h
```

It turns out, the `in` operator checks the index, not the values. I.e.

```
2 in df["two"]
```

evaluates to `True`

So one has to explicitly check for the values like this:

```
"h" in df["two"].values
```

This evaluates to `True`.